# Making Player Movement Less Floaty

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I am having issues with my runner game.
At the moment the movement feels way to icy because I have momentum, I have to stop going one way to go the other and it gives me this really icy effect I don't want.

I have tried upping friction but that results in my cube tumbling down the track

```
void FixedUpdate()
{

    rb.AddForce(0, 0, forwardForce * Time.deltaTime);

    if (Input.GetKey("d"))
    {
        rb.AddForce(sidewaysForce * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
    }

    if (Input.GetKey("a"))
    {
        rb.AddForce(-sidewaysForce * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
    }
```

I want the movement to be nice and smooth and snappy.

Comment: Is this related to Unity? If so, please edit your tags to include it. Doing so will help you attract developers who are better-equipped to solve your issue.

Comment: You will get your "icy effect" over whatever your deltatime is. What you're trying to add is enough jerk to stop current movement quickly. More force over less time will give you that.

Answer (score 1):

So, first of all: I would recommend not using AddForce for movement of the player, you can just rb.velocity = sth; (that would remove the icy).
But! If you really want it that way, I guess you could try:

```
rb.AddForce(-rb.velocity*(from 0 to 1 the less the less icy) + (the speed you want to change to));
```

I think this would work. Try it, but also, if it's a capsule collider, you could loon at the Character Controller that makes it all look better and simpler, or at the Rigidbody Controller (not a component, just a name to define what you are trying but with the rb.velocity method).

Hope it works!

Answer (score 0):

maybe this:

```
Vector3 CalculatedForce = -rb.velocity;
CalculatedForce.z = forwardForce * Time.deltaTime;
if (Input.GetKey("d"))
    CalculatedForce.x += sidewaysForce * Time.deltaTime;
else if (Input.GetKey("a"))
    CalculatedForce.x += -sidewaysForce * Time.deltaTime;

rb.AddForce(CalculatedForce, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
```